# Adding Items to ListView from Edittext

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-fragmentactivity

I have an Actiity where I have a simple Edittext and a button as shwown:

[image]

No I have a MainActivity which contains many fragments as shown:

[image]

This is my Code For passing edittext text to the main activity:

```
  addlist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnaddlist);
  findViewById(R.id.btnaddlist).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtlist);
                    Intent i = new Intent(CreateList.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    String ItemName = edit.getText().toString();
                    // Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
                    bundle.putString("ListItemName", ItemName);
                    // Add the bundle to the intent
                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

}
```

This is my Home fragment:

```
ListView lv;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.itemslistView);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    Bundle itemintent = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    String ItemName = itemintent.getString("ListItemName");

    if (itemintent.getString("ListItemName").equals("ItemName")) {
        /** Items entered by the user is stored in this ArrayList variable */
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(ItemName);
        /** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
        ArrayAdapter<String> Listadapter;
        Listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        Listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    return rootView;
}
```

I'm not getting any error in logcat..But its not able to add any text to listView on MainActivity.

Comment: did you set the adapter to your listView? lv.setAdapter(Listadapter);

Comment: @Rami-Yes I have set it to my ListView.

Comment: Where? i don't see it in your code.

Comment: @Rami-If so can you show me how do I set that ?

Comment: You already get data from activity then no need to use this   `if (itemintent.getString("ListItemName").equals("ItemName")) {`. remove this.

Comment: add *lv.setAdapter(Listadapter);* before *Listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();* . Btw i don't think you need to call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: And just set adapter to your listview you forgot to set

Answer (score 0):

You made the adapter but didn't call ListView#setAdapter()

Answer (score 0):

Change your Home fragment like that:

```
ListView lv;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.itemslistView);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        Bundle itemintent = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        String ItemName = itemintent.getString("ListItemName");

        if (ItemName.equals("ItemName")) {
            /** Items entered by the user is stored in this ArrayList variable */
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add(ItemName);
            /** Declaring an ArrayAdapter to set items to ListView */
            ArrayAdapter<String> Listadapter;
            Listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

            lv.setAdapter(Listadapter);
            Listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// i don't think this line is necessary

        }
        return rootView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is as below:

1. Start main activity
2. give a button to add item
3. on click of this button, call the activity(use **startActivityForResult** ) having edittext and a button
4. and on this button click,  **setResult** with intent extras and finish this activity.
5. it will to MainActivity. Here write your  **onActivityResult** method and handle it based on the result code. get your data from intent here.

Hope this answer helps you.